# "Invalid key" when writing data to Firebase from Android App using Kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to write data to Firebase from my Android App using this code..
package com.example.envir.databasetesting

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val name = name_txt.text.toString().trim()
        val email = email_txt.text.toString().trim()


        var myMap = hashMapOf<String, String>()


        save_bu.setOnClickListener{

            myMap.put(name,email)

            mdatabase.push().setValue(myMap)




        }




    }

}
```

I keep getting this error message:

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.envir.databasetesting, PID: 28042
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid key: . Keys must not contain '/', '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Do I need to add a key or somthing?  I thought that it would add a key for me by default?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

solved...

had to move the val into the button listener...

```
save_bu.setOnClickListener{
            val name = name_txt.text.toString().trim()
            val email = email_txt.text.toString().trim()
            myMap.put("name", name)
            myMap.put("email",email)

            mdatabase.push().setValue(myMap)
```

Comment: Consider [accepting this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/364194) so that others know it has been solved.

Answer (score 0):

The error is likely referring to the contents of your `name` val.  Check its contents and make sure it doesn't contain any of the prohibited values.

Typically, with database keys, you don't use an arbitrary value that your user may have entered.  Use only values that you've determined to form the schema for the data stored at a location.  So, you'll do better if your map looks like this instead:

```
myMap.put("name", name)
myMap.put("email", email)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error was fixed when I did this...

I changed this code....
save_bu.setOnClickListener{

```
        myMap.put(name,email)

        mdatabase.push().setValue(myMap)
```

to this...

save_bu.setOnClickListener{

```
        myMap.put("name", name)
        myMap.put("email",email)

        mdatabase.push().setValue(myMap)
```

now my problem is that it isn't saving the data I actually type in those edit text fields.  lol

Comment: Since you've already solved in the other answer, you might want to delete this one.